NestJS + Swagger: how to configure an ApiProperty as a list of strings separated by comma
In a NestJS application, given this ApiProperty from an ApiSchema:
@ApiProperty({ type: [String] })
type: string[];

it generates this field in the swagger UI, which allows the user to send multiple strings:

The Swagger is building the query with one parameter called type per entry:

...?type=item1&type=item2

but I need the swagger to build the query parameters with a single type with the values separated by comma:
...?type=item1,item2

Is it possible?
The package.json file has:
"@nestjs/swagger": "^7.3.1",


Change the type of the ApiProperty and add decorators.

You might try using isArray: true
@ApiProperty({ type: [String], isArray: true })
type: string[];

src: https://docs.nestjs.com/openapi/types-and-parameters#arrays

It doesn't change how the swagger UI sends the params: multiple 'type's per item in the provided array, instead of a single 'type' with the values separated by comma.
